# Suggestions to develop a Dashboard for Application Monitoring. Something similar to Nagios

Tags: java, architecture, monitoring, dashboard

My new assignment is to create a dashboard to monitor application health. I need to develop a dashboard similar to **Nagios**. Few questions to help me get started with it.

1. What are the metrics I should consider to show on dashboard in order to monitor the application?
2. Is there any framework which can read application logs and provide necessary metrics data?
3. Other then Application Logs, Is there any other source which can provide data related to application health?

I am working on a J2EE application which has UI in flex, backend is SQL Server database and application servers are Tomcat/JBoss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just two words for you: **USE [NAGIOS](http://www.nagios.org)**

#### Edited:

Nagios is free for up to 7 nodes. Here's a snip from the [Nagios pricing page](http://www.nagios.com/products/nagiosxi/pricing):

> **Free License For Small Environments**
>
> Have a small environment you need monitored? Nagios XI will monitor up to seven (7) hosts/nodes with unlimited services free of charge! Just select the free license in the XI administration interface. Perfect for SOHO and personal use. Support services are not included when using a free license

Comment: You are right but I am from a small company and can not afford it right now. Is their any similar free tools available?

Comment: Three words: **NAGIOS IS FREE**